# What is the order of execution in content related objects?

Tags: apex, trigger, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I have a scenario to insert the content document link for sharing the contentdocument with contentworkspace (library) when the contentdocument is created.

I want to write a trigger to achieve this.

I have some questions regarding this:

1. Which should I prefer, contentdocument or contentversion for writing trigger?
2. What is the order of execution when a content version record is created with no contentdocumentId, like contentdocument is created first or contentversion, and after what operations will my trigger run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the process of uploading a document, Salesforce initially creates a `ContentVersion`. Following this, a `ContentDocument` record is automatically generated, associated with this initial `ContentVersion`. It's worth noting that `ContentDocument` cannot be directly inserted. To monitor and act upon a document upload, a trigger on `contentdocument` is a suitable choice.

Here's what happens when a fresh document is uploaded:

First, Salesforce creates a new `ContentVersion`. Here BeforeInsert trigger runs for `ContentVersion`.
Then, it automatically sets up a ContentDocument record. The ContentDocumentId on the `ContentVersion` gets assigned with the ID of this freshly created `ContentDocument`. And the contentversion trigger runs its AfterInsert trigger with contentdocumentid.

For your sharing purpose you can write your trigger on `Contentdocument`

Comment: Previously, I had written trigger on contentdocument which is used to make a contentdocumentlink for sharing the contentdocument with library(contentworkspace) when document get uploaded. but, when i did it, i get the following error : Invalid cross reference Id. When i done the same thing on contentversion trigger (after insert), i faced no problem and my document shared with the library. What can be the reason?

Comment: Can you please add some scenario which differentiates the use of trigger on contentversion and contentdocument.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the order of execution when a content version record is created with no contentdocumentId, like contentdocument is created first or contentversion, and after what operations will my trigger run?

ContentVersion always creates ContentDocument for itself. You can check it with this code:

```
String OUTPUT_DOCUMENT_NAME = 'OUTPUT_DOCUMENT_NAME';

ContentVersion newVersion = new ContentVersion(Title = OUTPUT_DOCUMENT_NAME, PathOnClient = OUTPUT_DOCUMENT_NAME + '.csv',
                VersionData = Blob.valueOf('123'), ContentLocation = 'S');

insert newVersion;

System.assert(String.isNotBlank([SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :newVersion.Id].ContentDocumentId));
```

> Which should I prefer, contentdocument or contentversion for writing trigger?

Write the trigger on ContentDocument (after insert). ContentDocumentLink needs ContentDocumentId (not ContentVersionId).

Comment: Yes you are correct, running it on ContentDocument makes sense. Aaaahhhh what was I thinking.....

Comment: Previously, I had written trigger on contentdocument which is used to make a contentdocumentlink for sharing the contentdocument with library(contentworkspace) when document get uploaded. but, when i did it, i get the following error : Invalid cross reference Id. When i done the same thing on contentversion trigger (after insert), i faced no problem and my document shared with the library. What can be the reason?